# Why does this C++ polymorphism not work?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I don't understand why this inheritance doesn't work. I have the following setup:

```
struct Shape{}
struct Stain : Shape {}
```

Now, why can't I do the following:

```
vector<Shape> shapes;
Stain stain();
shapes.push_back(stain);
```

I would this expect this to be working since `Stain` is a subclass of `Shape`, so I should be able to put a `Stain` into a `vector<Shape>`? Or is this even conceptually wrong and what I am trying to do is indeed not possible?

Comment: Why your particular code doesn't build, look up "(most) vexing parse." In short, `stain` is a function: drop the `()` to make it an object. Then, look up "object slicing" to find why it wouldn't do what you'd expect.

Comment: This is wrong. `vector` defined like this is storing actual values, so your `Stain` will get truncated.

Comment: To get polymorphism in C++, you need to use references or pointers. Also, when you push_back a Stain into a vector of Shape:s, you will get slicing. I.e., the Stain is brutally cut down to the size of a Shape, not good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For polymorphism in C++ you need reference semantics. The easiest way to achieve that would be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>`.

Alternatively, if you want to be able to copy your shapes, look at `value_ptr` concept. A lot of implementations also allow COW (Copy-on-Write). Essentially for nearly all purposes it works just like a value, e.g. a copy of it makes a copy of the value it holds and allocates it.

The obvious change is that **you can't treat your vector as a POD memory block anymore**.

Comment: Where could one find boost's implementation of value_ptr? I guess it is hidden away somewhere in some unrelated library?

Comment: @juanchopanza A quick googling shows that they don't expose it directly. I think I'll edit it a bit to avoid confusion.